# jq combine two results one command

Tags: json, curl, jq

i want to output two values from this below json.

the value `.next` and value of `.digest` when `.name = "latest"` and `architecture = "amd64"`. I got these two working separated from each other but i want both results in one output from one curl command.

```
{
  "count": 685,
  "next": "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/grafana/grafana/tags/?page=2&page_size=100",
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "creator": 4132603,
      "id": 190096972,
      "images": [
        {
          "architecture": "amd64",
          "features": "",
          "variant": null,
          "digest": "sha256:1e180fcaede581b8cc8e2ce8bc010daff9c64972023a0faaf226d92bd9840113",
          "os": "linux",
          "os_features": "",
          "os_version": null,
          "size": 91402044,
          "status": "active",
          "last_pulled": "2022-07-06T03:17:56.450051Z",
          "last_pushed": "2022-06-28T14:15:09.891118Z"
        },
        {
          "architecture": "arm64",
          "features": "",
          "variant": "v8",
          "digest": "sha256:834e26ec5e5f4e5eb2410147c12b060143906de04f35eb51cae8285e9b646a56",
          "os": "linux",
          "os_features": "",
          "os_version": null,
          "size": 81476918,
          "status": "active",
          "last_pulled": "2022-07-06T09:03:47.33578Z",
          "last_pushed": "2022-06-28T14:15:10.030013Z"
        },
        {
          "architecture": "arm",
          "features": "",
          "variant": "v7",
          "digest": "sha256:3bc954cb89f35bdc0705a381ab9b9a49b014074fbc555c61bf7572cb0965f323",
          "os": "linux",
          "os_features": "",
          "os_version": null,
          "size": 82128685,
          "status": "active",
          "last_pulled": "2022-07-06T09:33:22.228128Z",
          "last_pushed": "2022-06-28T14:15:10.159549Z"
        }
      ],
      "last_updated": "2022-06-28T14:15:10.331474Z",
      "last_updater": 2978857,
      "last_updater_username": "grafanaci",
      "name": "latest",
      "repository": 135617,
      "full_size": 91402044,
      "v2": true,
      "tag_status": "active",
      "tag_last_pulled": "2022-07-06T09:33:22.228128Z",
      "tag_last_pushed": "2022-06-28T14:15:10.331474Z"
    },
```

Command 1

```
curl -s "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/grafana/grafana/tags/" | jq --raw-output '.results[] | select(.name=="latest").images[] | select(.architecture=="amd64").digest'
```

result: `sha256:1e180fcaede581b8cc8e2ce8bc010daff9c64972023a0faaf226d92bd9840113`

Command 2:

```
curl -s "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/grafana/grafana/tags/" | jq --raw-output '.next'
```

result: `https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/grafana/grafana/tags/?page=2`

What i want is the two results as one ouput like this:
`sha256:1e180fcaede581b8cc8e2ce8bc010daff9c64972023a0faaf226d92bd9840113, https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/grafana/grafana/tags/?page=2`

But how can i do this?

Comment: To output both in separate lines, separate them with a comma: `jq -r '(.results[] | select(.name=="latest").images[] | select(.architecture=="amd64").digest), .next'` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/25xeBsv36mI) -- To output them separated by a comma, make it an array, and use `join` on that: `jq -r '[(.results[] | select(.name=="latest").images[] | select(.architecture=="amd64").digest), .next] | join(",")'` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AkeAZm5vbyq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap your filter in `()`, the original object will still be available en can be targeted with `.next` as done in the example.

Using a `,`, we can pass the input to the next filter.

```
(.results[] | select(.name=="latest").images[] | select(.architecture=="amd64").digest), .next
```

```json
"sha256:1e180fcaede581b8cc8e2ce8bc010daff9c64972023a0faaf226d92bd9840113"
"https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/grafana/grafana/tags/?page=2&page_size=100"
```

#### [Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/BjuSiUnBBnF)